# Не отображается иконка html страницы

Tags: html, html5

Проблема в том не отображается иконка страницы хотя путь к ней правильный.

Вот код:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="wigth=device-wigth" initial-scale=1.0>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="icon" href="img/home-icon.png">
<head>
    <title>Главная</title>
</head>
 <body>
    ....My code
 </body>
</html>
```

Формат иконки (.png). Браузер Google Chrome.

Спасибо!

Comment: Если путь href="img/home-icon.png" указан верно, то в браузере нажмите клавиши ctrl+F5

Comment: Можете дать ссылку на саму страницу или она на локалке у вас?

Comment: в Хроме может быть недостаточно ctrl+F5 - придётся в истории почистить кеш

Comment: Страница в данный момент на локале показать не могу. Кеш очищал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Неправильный `rel`
2. Относительный путь
3. Проверь http-заголовки

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/home-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" href="/img/home-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="/img/home-icon.png">
```

PS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13827325/4928642